# Is there a pause shorter than a comma?

Tags: punctuation, commas, orthography

I'm writing a poem, and like how it's flowing. But I find that a tiny pause shorter than a comma would do tremendous. Is there such a mark or multitude of symbols to make a short pause?

Comment: In a word, no . . .

Comment: The movement from one line to the next can imply a short pause, even if there's no punctuation. Or write "(a tiny pause)" in the line? :-)

Comment: A demisemiquaver rest? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-second_note

Answer (score 1):

I really believe
You should use
Line breaks
To give people
A chance
To think.

`Maybe  you could use multiple spaces?`

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't an option in places where line-breaks aren't permitted, especially in inline technical documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your poetic style, you can add a syllable to a word to increase the length of the sentence or line. However, it's poetry; that probably won't work. But because it's poetry, there's nothing against using two or more spaces after a word. The reader will automatically slow down if for nothing else because it's unusual.

Answer (score -1):

Semicolons and colons have been relegated to the fringes more and more in the last hundred years. A comma seemed relatively short in the old days, but now it can seem oppressive. An unintended consequence of the continuing distaste for periodic writing.